# MKMapview customannotationview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview

Iam working in MKMapview customannotationview, and succeeded in customizing the pin drop to my own image using the below code,

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *parkingAnnotationIdentifier=@"ParkingAnnotationIdentifier";

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotationClass class]]){
    //Try to get an unused annotation, similar to uitableviewcells
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView=[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:parkingAnnotationIdentifier];
    //If one isn't available, create a new one
        if(!annotationView){
            annotationView=[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:parkingAnnotationIdentifier];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my image.png"];

        }
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

ie, I customized the image of annotation view to my image, but I need a bubble or label in the right upper corner of the annotation view as below,

How to get that? your help will surely get appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MKAnnotationView is just inherited from UIView. so you can add your own subview to it.

Solution:

1. Add banner to top right
2. If you want deal touch event on
   banner, you should deal hitTest problem. just override below to
   expand touch bounding.

   ```
   - (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point
              withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   ```